# Cascading dropdown, pass <option> value as ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been building a jQuery based cascading dropdown, using the solution found here [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834906/cascading-dropdown-on-javascript):
Javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var locations = {
        'Germany': ['Duesseldorf', 'Leinfelden-Echterdingen', 'Eschborn'],
        'Spain': ['Barcelona'],
        ...
    }

    var $locations = $('#location');
    $('#country').change(function () {
        var country = $(this).val(), lcns = locations[country] || [];

        var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn) {
            return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
        }).join('');

        $locations.html(html)
    });
});
```

This works great, however I need to pass an ID of the city, not the city name itself. I've figured out how to add a key to a value ( I am less than noob when it comes to JS ):

Javascript:

```
var locations = {
    'Germany': ['Duesseldorf', 'Leinfelden-Echterdingen', 'Eschborn'],
    'Spain': { 4 : 'Barcelona', 15 : 'Madrid', 21 : 'Marabella'],
    ...
}
```

Question is: how do I pass that id onto the `<option>` value...?

Javascript:

```
return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parameters of `map()` callbak function for text & value. Change your `map()` like following.

```
var html = $.map(lcns, function (text, val) {
    return '<option value="' + val + '">' + text + '</option>'
}).join('');
```

And your object is wrong. Last `]` should be `}`

```
'Spain': { 4 : 'Barcelona', 15 : 'Madrid', 21 : 'Marabella'],
//---------------------------------------------------------^----
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a standardized object structure within an array instead of using the id as keys of an object. It is easier to read and arrays are generally easier to work with for repeating structures

```
'Spain': [

    {  id: 4,  city: 'Barcelona' }, 
    {  id: 15, city: 'Madrid' }, 
    {  id: 21, city: 'Marabella' }

]

var html = $.map(lcns, function( item) {
        return '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.city + '</option>'
}).join('');
```

Comment: I like this solution! However in my case I went with Azim's solution: an array is being dynamically built by a PHP's loop and actually will never be touched neither by me nor any other programmer in the future.

Comment: Would take only minor adjustments to that php loop to change to this structure. Note that the resultant object you create has no display order and can not be sorted  or filtered whereas a true javascript array can.

Comment: True, cannot be sorted but again: I place the array items in order I need using that PHP loop - the array is just a final result of bunch of PHP calculations etc. Having said that I am gonna go and re-do the PHP output according to your suggestions :) Thanks!

Comment: You keep calling it an array.... since javascript doesn't have associative arrays like php does...it becomes a javascript object not array

Answer (score 0):

It's more custom to build the object as follows:

```
{ id: 1, city: 'Duesseldorf' };
```

If you're willing to do that, you can do something like:

```
var locations = {
    'Germany': [
    {id: 1, city: 'Duesseldorf'}, {id: 2, city: 'Leinfelden'}]
}; 

var lcns = locations['Germany']; //Just an example 

$.map(lcns, function(lcn) {
    console.log(lcn.id); 
    console.log(lcn.city); 
    return '<option value="' + lcn.id + '">' + lcn.city + '</option>'
}).join('');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npjdfn0y/2/

Might I also suggest to change your object into an array of countries:

```
[
    { id: 1, country: 'Germany', cities: [
        { id: 1, city: 'Duesseldorf'}, { id: 2, city: 'Leinfelden' }
    ]}, 
    { id: 2, country: 'Spain', cities: [ 
        { id: 11, city: 'Barcelona' }, { id: 12, city: 'Madrid' }
    ]}
];
```